# GPS is not working on my Android phone

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I have a working application on the emulator, but when I try on my phone, its not.
On the emulator, I send a fake position to the phone and it receive it without problems with this code:

```
private class GPSListener implements LocationListener{
    private ProgressDialog waitingDialog;
    public GPSListener(Context c) {
        this.waitingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(c, "", c.getString(R.string.sWaitingMessage), true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
        int longitude = (int) Math.round(loc.getLongitude() * 1000000);
        int latitude = (int) Math.round(loc.getLatitude() * 1000000);
        this.waitingDialog.dismiss();
        GeoPoint currentLocation = new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude);
        GPSPosition.this.whenPositionFound(currentLocation);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

However, when I try on my phone, onLocationChanged() is never called.
I activate the GPS search with this:

```
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    GPSListener gpsListner = new GPSListener(c);
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsListner);
```

and here is my logs, full of this:

```
03-23 14:04:28.411: VERBOSE/GpsLocationProvider(148): SV count: 0 ephemerisMask: 0 almanacMask: ffffffff
03-23 14:04:28.411: DEBUG/RPC(148): written RPC packet size: [24]
03-23 14:04:28.421: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet
03-23 14:04:28.431: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet size: [284]
03-23 14:04:28.431: VERBOSE/libgps(148): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
03-23 14:04:28.431: DEBUG/RPC(148): written RPC packet size: [24]
03-23 14:04:28.431: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet
03-23 14:04:28.431: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet size: [284]
03-23 14:04:28.431: VERBOSE/libgps(148): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
03-23 14:04:28.431: DEBUG/RPC(148): written RPC packet size: [24]
03-23 14:04:28.441: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet
03-23 14:04:28.441: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet size: [284]
03-23 14:04:28.441: VERBOSE/libgps(148): DeferredActionThread pthread_cond_wait returned
03-23 14:04:28.441: DEBUG/RPC(148): written RPC packet size: [24]
03-23 14:04:28.451: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet
03-23 14:04:28.451: DEBUG/RPC(148): read RPC packet size: [284]
```

What am I doing wrong ? I tried inside/outside, Google Map is locating me very well and quickly even inside my house.

Comment: Is GPS enabled on the device?

Comment: yes, the signal is firing on the "top bar" as on the emulator when I send a dummy location. The GPS is working great with my phone on google maps.

Comment: Did you have try with a criteria? cause maybe the last LocationProvider was another than your GPS.

Comment: That's right, the location is working with LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER. However, Im not sure it solves the problem, the accuracy is less good.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting GPS coordinates properly is always an issue in Android. After trying lots of stuff I finally saw how the [Android camera app](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/camera/Camera.java;h=66b180517098aa8e41cc7e184058813462253127;hb=80d500c4671ee11ca331479d214641bcb32cea0a) was embedding the coordinates in the clicked image. The best thing to do is to register for both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER and keep minDistance as 0 when you request for location updates.

It usually takes some time to get a GPS fix, so if something in your activity depends on the location, then check for a location after say every 250ms.

To get the location you first check if you have a fix from the GPS and then from the network provider.